# Will moving Images to CDN effect Google Image search results?

Tags: google-search, cdn, images, image-hosting

I'f moving images on a site to a CDN how does this effect the image results in Google image search?

Will any images come up in Google image search coming from the site?

Answer (score 1):

Google ranks images based on the source page and not the file location, so it shouldn't be a problem... if anything you may see a slight improve on page rankings due page speed being  a factor.

Comment: Not if you do it right. Basically, set up a webserver entry in Google Webmaster Tools, point it at your media subdomain and in our case, we found that it increased the number of images Google found to be relevant for search.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for that? I'm facing the same issue and very wary about changing image URLs for highly ranked images.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a source since its common knownledge that CDN's improve SEO not harm and is used by the most popular sites in the world.